# Update an oracle table from another table in SAS

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I have a 10 million row table in Oracle which I inserted from SAS. Every week this table is updated in SAS with some new rows and some changes in some of the rows based on certain criteria like date, Location etc. I know how to append the table in oracle from SAS.
This is the code that I am using currently.

```
libname ABC oracle user='aaa' password='ppp' path = xyz;
proc append base=table_10m
 data=additional_rows; 
run;
```

Before doing this I first have to identify the added rows in the SAS table. I have to do the same thing in SAS for updated rows as well. Here is an example of the old and new table:

```
Old Table
colA  colB          colC       colD
BAC   Jul-31-2014    45        2.24
CAD   Jul-31-2014    98        10.2

New Table
colA  colB          colC       colD
BAC   Jul-31-2014    65        2.24
CAD   Jul-31-2014    98        10.2
BAC   AUG-01-2014    22         3.3
ABC   AUG-01-2014    32         5.2
```

As you can see the new table has 2 additional rows and row1 colc value was updated.

This is the code I am using to update the table in oracle from SAS.

```
PROC SQL; 
UPDATE old_table as a SET new_table = (SELECT b.colc
FROM sas.new_table as b 
WHERE a.colA=b.colA and
a.colB = b.colB
) 
WHERE exists 
(select * from sas.new_table as b 
WHERE a.colA=b.colA and a.colB = b.colB
); 
QUIT;
```

Is there a way to update the old table in Oracle to the new table from SAS with the additional rows and changed rows ? Is there an easier way, please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to identify it to me seems to be a join or `exists` query (or data step merge).  Assuming you have an index on the oracle table and the SAS table on the ID columns (`colA` and `colB` in your example), this should be fairly quick.

```
proc sql;
  create view sas.additional_rows as
   select * from sas.new_table S
     where not exists (
       select 1 from abc.old_table O
         where O.colA=S.colA
           and O.colB=S.colB
     );

  create view sas.to_update as
   select * from sas.new_table S
     where exists (
       select 1 from abc.old_table O
         where O.colA=S.colA
           and O.colB=S.colB
           and O.colC ne S.colC
     );
quit;
```

Then `proc append` from that view (or make it a table if that turns out to give better performance - table might be faster if it's relatively small proportion).  Add `BCP` or whichever appropriate option allows bulk loading/copying (`BCP` for SQL Server, not sure about Oracle's equivalent) if you want faster uploading of large datasets.

To add the updated ones, I would delete from Oracle the rows to update and then re-insert them; I find that usually faster than an update statement, but I'm not an expert there.  You could also put the combination of `additional_rows` and `to_update` in a temporary table and use the `merge into` syntax of the other answer.

Comment: Thanks Joe ! What would be 'select 1 ' ? Currently I don't have an index on my oracle table. Can you guide me to any article or paper which provides a good way of indexing oracle tables ? I appreciate that. I did tried searching online and really couldn't understand what columns I should index in order to make the search faster.

Comment: Not an oracle expert, so I'd just google indexes.  If you don't have an index, this query will work, just slower.  Same for SAS table - you should index that also if not already.  You should index the columns you're joining on, assuming they're good candidates for index (the combination of the two uniquely or close to uniquely identifies a row).

Comment: Also, this code will give me all the new rows and updated rows. If I use proc append then all the rows will be added to the old table. But I would want to update the value of colc based on a cola and colb match.

Answer (score 0):

Merge is probably what you look for:

```
merge into old_table o
using sas.new_table n
on (a.colA=b.colA and a.colB = b.colB)
when matched then
     update set o.colC = n.colC, o.colD = n.colD
when not matched then
     insert (colA, colB, colC, colD) values(n.colA, n.colB, n.colC, n.colD);
```

Comment: Given the user has the full 10m+ data as a SAS table, this would require him uploading the whole thing to an Oracle table anyway - might as well just rewrite the whole table then.

Comment: thanks Emmanuel ! This is a good solution but would this be a good option for a 10 million table update every week ?